# Vs code live server extension application not found problem

Tags: visual-studio-code

when i try to go live using the vs code extension live server an error message will pop up saying "Application not found".

Answer (score 1):

I just faced this same problem and this is how I solved it.

Go to the live server extension in VS Code, click on the settings icon, click on **Extension Settings**, scroll to **Live Server › Settings: Custom Browser** (`liveServer.settings.CustomBrowser`).

Then choose a browser, i.e change it from null to the browser you want to use, then scroll down again to **Live Server › Settings: Use Local Ip** (`liveServer.settings.useLocalIp`) and check it.

Then continue your work, I hope this helps.